# .htaccess redirect http/https www to https non-www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm trying furiously with our wordpress sites on google cloud to redirect everything such as https://www. to https://example.com

I'm using the following currently, which is diverting most in example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content\/cache\/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It directs links such as; http://www.example.com to https://example.com

but it will not re-direct links using https://www.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
# www -> https without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
# http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/cache/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try and it should work just as fine .. that's all you need to actually redirect all 'http' requests to 'https' BUT mind it you still need a valid SSL certificate installed on your site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```